# Failed to load keystore type [PKCS12] after upgrade to Java 17

Tags: java, ssl

I run my Springboot application with ssl on localhost.  I have some integration tests that validate that ssl works:

*application.properties*

```
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:ssl/localhost.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=localhost_ssl
server.ssl.key-alias=localhost_ssl
server.ssl.enabled=true
```

*integration test*

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("getSslTestParameters")
void onlyAllowSecureCallsToEndpoint(boolean includesSecure, ResultMatcher expectedStatus) throws Exception {
    MockHttpServletRequestBuilder postCall = post("/api/tutors/register")
            .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(TutorRegistrationDTO.builder().build()))
            .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
            .with(csrf());
    if (includesSecure) {
        postCall.secure(true);
    }
    mvc.perform(postCall).andExpect(expectedStatus);
}

private static Stream<Arguments> getSslTestParameters() {
    return Stream.of(
            Arguments.of(true, status().isOk()),
            Arguments.of(false, status().isFound()));
}
```

This test worked fine in Java 8 when I run it with IntelliJ and Maven.  Now I did an upgrade to Java 17 and it still works when I run it with IntelliJ, but it stopped working when I run a Maven build.  I get the following error:

```
IOException: Failed to load keystore type [PKCS12] with path [jar:file:/C:/mypath/target/app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/ssl/localhost.p12] due to [Illegal char <:> at index 3: jar:file:\C:\mypath\target\app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!\ssl\localhost.p12]
```

I can confirm that `localhost.p12` is available within the jar, but it seems to have a problem with parsing the .p12 file.  I assume the file itself is not wrong since the test still works with IntelliJ.

I already verified that IntelliJ is not giving me a false positive by setting `postCall.secure(false)` and verified that a test fails as expected.

Did something change with the way ssl works between Java 8 and 17?  I couldn't find anything related in the documentation.

EDIT: I should add that the application still runs without a problem.  The problem lies purely with the test.

Comment: Oh no.  I only just started to read the exception more clearly.  It's not complaining about the .p12 file, it is complaining about the path.  It cannot parse the path with `jar:...` it seems.

Answer (score 0):

It was no longer interpreting the path to the jar correctly from Maven. It complained about the path `jar:...`, the semicolon.

I solved it by copying `/ssl/localhost.p12` to the test resources of my integration test Maven module.

I have no explanation for why it could interpret the jar path in Java 8 and not in Java 17 though.